# Timestamp in [hh:mm:ss:msms] format C++

Tags: c++, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I wanted to write a little loop that print timestamps in this format [hh:mm:ss:msms]. Best case would be a seperate function to do so. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

If you want that specific format, the only way I know of is parsing the time since epoch counter by yourself (Or getting the default time format as I show below, parsing all of its elements and rearranging them yourself in another string).

Meanwhile, you could do it in the default format like this (include ctime and chrono)

```
auto t = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto ptr = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(t);
char time[255];
auto frm = ctime_s(time, 255, &ptr);
printf("%s\n", time);
getchar();
```

Output:

```
Sat Jun 20 07:28:36 2020
```

**Edit:**

I have found a way to do this with standard functions:

```
char timestamp[50]{ 0 };
std::time_t time = std::time(nullptr);
std::strftime(timestamp, 30, "[%H:%M:%S]", std::localtime(&time));
```

Unfortunately, I do not believe there is a standard way to get the current number of milliseconds maybe because the OS does not keep track of that.

When you see timestamps in other people's programs, the millisecond count is probably counted by them (But I may be wrong).

If you want to do that, you can get the number of milliseconds (since epoch or since start of OS, depending on what function you use) at the start of the program then every time you calculate a timestamp, get it again and subtract the original one from it.

Let's say you use Windows, you can do this:

```
// Get the initial tick
unsigned int starttick = GetTickCount();
... Do your stuff here
// Get the current tick:
unsigned int stoptick = GetTickCount();
// Subtract current tick from start tick to get elapsed milliseconds (roughly)
printf("%d", (stoptick - starttick));
```

Or you can use Chrono:

```
auto s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
Sleep(1500);
auto st = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(st - s).count();
printf("%lld", ms);
getchar();
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Can you explain me exactly what you did there? I need to transform it to my format thats a bit rough being a beginner. Or can you try to solve it

Comment: I'm garbage at working with strings but I'll give it a try I guess